# converting time complexity from O(N squared) to O(N) in radx sort

Tags: python, sorting, radix

results = [['AAA', 'AAA', 65], ['AAA', 'AAB', 82],....]

```
def __flatten(A):
    return reduce(lambda x,y : x + y, A)

def radxsrt(A,num_dig):
    for digit in range(0,num_dig):
        Bucket = [[] for i in range(10)]
        for item in A:
            num = item[2] // 10 ** (digit) % 10
            Bucket[num].append(item)
        A = __flatten(Bucket)
    return A

def radx(list):
    num_digits = max(map(lambda x: x[2], list))
    a = radxsrt(list,num_digits)
    return a

top10matches = radx(results)
```

I've tried reducing the time complexity of the algo to O(N) but haven't come up with any solution yet. is there any way to convert that nested for loop to a single for loop.

by the way, the algo is for sorting a nested list with the 3rd(2nd index / score) number of the sub list.

Comment: the loops don't iterate over the number of elements, one iterates the number of elements and the other the number of digits, giving a complexity of `O(nd)` which is actually the best you can achieve with radix sort

Comment: Is this for some exercise, or why don't you just use Python's built-in sorting?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Actually not "number of digits", that's part of the problem.